# jQuery search bar live update

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to make a search bar that update a list of items found in the database which like the value of this search bar. Here is my code for the bar :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#search').keyup(function () {
        $('#results').html('');

        let searchValue = $(this).val();

        if(searchValue !== ''){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '../controller/searchItem.php',
                data: 'data=' + encodeURIComponent(searchValue),
                success: function(data){
                    if(data !== ""){
                        $('#results').append(data);
                    }else{
                        document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = "<div style='font-size: 20px; text-align: center; margin-top: 10px'><p>Oups, ce que vous cherchez n'existe pas encore !</p></div>";
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    })
});
```

But actually when I'm doing Shift+Letter, it sends two request because of the ".keyup". I'd like to send only one request with this combination, and without having to lose the focus on the search bar or having to press Enter (in other words dynamically).

Did someone have any tips for my problem ? Many thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending an ajax request on a keyup is not really smart.
Why? because I can spam my keyboard 1000 times and it will send 1000 requests.
What you might want to do, is send a request after the user finished typing.

```
var typingTimer;
var doneTypingInterval = 1000; // Trigger the request 1 second/1000 ms after user done typing.
var input = $('#input'); // Your input

input.on('keyup', function () {
  clearTimeout(typingTimer);
  typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
});

input.on('keydown', function () {
  clearTimeout(typingTimer);
});

// user is done, send ajax request.
function doneTyping () {
   let searchValue = $('#input').val();

   if(searchValue !== ''){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '../controller/searchItem.php',
                data: 'data=' + encodeURIComponent(searchValue),
                success: function(data){
                    if(data !== ""){
                        $('#results').append(data);
                    }else{
                        document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = "<div style='font-size: 20px; text-align: center; margin-top: 10px'><p>Oups, ce que vous cherchez n'existe pas encore !</p></div>";
                    }
                }
            })
        }
}
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you ! I just added "$(document).ready(function()..." at the start.

Comment: No problem! the $(document).ready() is not necessary if you're putting the script tag in the bottom of the body / after the jquery import. :)